# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl Chapter 9 (Listing 9.43)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org, ruby-2.0

I'm following Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. I have reached chapter 9. There are some codes that I don't understand. Please see below, line 4, why do we need a `!` in front of `current_user?(user)` to make it `!current_user?(user)`Didn't we need `true && true` for the if statement to pass so Admin can see the delete action.

If a user logged in and is a admin, then `current_user.admin? == true`, `current_user?(user) = true`, and `!current_user?(user)` will be false and the if statement won't pass.

**_user.html.erb**

```
<li>
<%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
<%= link_to user.name, user %>
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
| <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
</li>
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end

def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
end
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Admins can delete users and they can't delete themselves.

From [railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-destroying_users) Chapter 9.4:

> administrative users should see such links, and by clicking on a delete link we expect an admin to delete the user

and

> Note also that we have added a test to verify that the admin does not see a link to delete himself

So:

`current_user.admin?` means "is the current user an admin?"

`!current_user?(user)` means "is the current user different from the user I am displaying?"

Put together, `<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>` as a test for displaying the `Delete` link means that the delete link only displays for Admins but not when their own `user` details are being displayed. That is, only Admins can delete users and they can't delete themselves.

Remember, the user view is displaying a list of the users, not just the current user. In this context, `user` means the model of the user that is being displayed by the view at that time.

Check [this image](http://railstutorial.org/images/figures/index_delete_links_rails_3_bootstrap-full.png) and note that `Example User` does not have a delete link but everyone else does.

Comment: Can you explain how this code `<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>` = Only Admins can delete users and they can't delete themselves. Thanks

Comment: cos `true && true => true` and `true && false => false`, how can the admin see the delete action if it's `true && false` ?

Comment: Updated answer with further explanations

Comment: Exactly right - admins can't see the delete link when the second answer resolves to `false` - that is, when the displayed `user` is `current_user`.